# JSF f:selectItems using List error

Tags: java, jsf

**Facelet code:**

```
<h:selectOneMenu id = "country" label = "country" value = "#{beanController.countryResidence}">
    <f:selectItems value = "#{countries.countries}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Bean Code:**

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true, name = "countries")
@ApplicationScoped
public class CountriesConstants {
        private List<SelectItem> countries;
        public CountriesConstants(){
            countries.add(new SelectItem("DE", "Germany"));
            countries.add(new SelectItem("JA", "Japan"));
            countries.add(new SelectItem("RU", "Russia"));
            countries.add(new SelectItem("US", "United States"));
        }
        public List<SelectItem> getCountries() {
            return countries;
        }
        public void setCountries(List<SelectItem> countries) {
            this.countries = countries;
        }
}
```

**The Error**

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: com.mysite.util.CountriesConstants.
```

I followed some tutorials step by step but I keep getting this error. I tried making the List *static* and initialise the values in a static block but I get the same error.

**EDIT:**

The new **Bean Code**

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true, name="constants")
@ApplicationScoped
public class Constants {

    public static final String VALIDATE_DETAILED = "detailed";
    public static final List<SelectItem> countries;

    static{
        countries = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        countries.add(new SelectItem("DE", "Germany"));
        countries.add(new SelectItem("JA", "Japan"));
        countries.add(new SelectItem("RU", "Russia"));
        countries.add(new SelectItem("US", "United States"));
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }
}
```

This seems to work but I find it weird that I can access a static attribute with a non static method. If I remove the *getCOuntries()* method an error saying that *no countries attribute exists* is thrown.

Comment: When getting an exception always look at the bottommost part of the stack trace. You have had there a `NullPointerException` which is very self-explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your bean constructor, you must create your List first, try this:

```
public CountriesConstants(){
   countries = new LinkedList<SelectItem>();
   countries.add(new SelectItem("DE", "Germany"));
   countries.add(new SelectItem("JA", "Japan"));
   countries.add(new SelectItem("RU", "Russia"));
   countries.add(new SelectItem("US", "United States"));
}
```

Besides, your `<f:selectItems>` tag should have more attribute. Something like this:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{countries.countries}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.name}" itemValue="#{c.id}" />
```

**UPDATE**: suppose you have the following controller

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BeanController {
   private String countryResidence;
}
```

Comment: Why should I specify the _itemLabel_ and _itemValue_ if the countries list already contains SelectItem instances?

Comment: It seems to work just fine without any other attributes. I checked the source code as well and the result is the desired one. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to accomplish the same results but with a static block instead. This would be a better solution for me because my project architecture. Can something like this be done?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure what you meant by static block?

Comment: `static` only means that your `countries` variable is shared among all instances of your ManagedBean `constants`. You, of course, can get it out with non-static function. Even though it's recommended that you should use static function to access static variables, Java does not have any rules that force you to do so. Anyway, since your ManagedBean has `@ApplicationScoped`, there is only 1 instance of that ManagedBean at any given time. Hence, declaring it with `static` doesn't have any meaningful results. You should keep it `private List<SelectItem> countries;`

Comment: Alternatively, keep the SelectItems out of your bean and build a traditional Map (use TreeMap to preserve the order). The trend in JSF is to use  as little JSF API classes as possible and resorting to standard Java SE collections whenever possible/practical.

Comment: @MrJames: you're wrong about the `<f:selectItems>` with `List<SelectItem>`. It works perfectly fine this way without `var` and `itemLabel`/`itemValue`. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html

Comment: @BalusC Thanks! I have always used List of objects with `itemLabel` and `itemValue`. A new thing to learn then! :)

Comment: It's a leftover of JSF 1.x. The `<f:selectItems var>` is new since JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your arrayList first

```
private List<SelectItem> countries = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
```

Your facelets code seems **fine**.

Answer (score 2):

```
private final List<SelectItem> countries = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
```

Initialize and declare List as "final" if you want to make the countries object not be instantiated again. It is a good practice to use final which improves readability of the code as well.

Comment: hmmmm are you sure that this is necessary? Since this bean has `@ApplicationScoped`, as long as there is no additional calls that re-initialize this list, I think it will stay the same throughout the application's lifetime.

Comment: It's not necessary of course, but I would  assign it an immutable list to be sure. If it's also final then that's an extra guarantee and declaration of intent for those reading the code.